# Identify itunes:keywords and itunes:category individually with feedparser?

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I'm using [feedparser](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser) to parse rss feeds such as https://www.relay.fm/analogue/feed and can't work out how explicitly identify the `itunes:category` values.

Looking at the [feedparser itunes tests](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/tree/f1dd1bb923ebfe6482fc2521c1f150b4032289ec/tests/wellformed/itunes) it appears that both the `itunes:keywords` and `itunes:category` values are put into the `feed['tags']` dictionary.

From the tests for `category`:

```
<!--
Description: iTunes channel category
Expect:      not bozo and feed['tags'][0]['term'] == 'Technology'
-->
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/DTDs/Podcast-1.0.dtd">
    <channel>
        <itunes:category text="Technology"></itunes:category>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

and then `keywords`:

```
<!--
Description: iTunes channel keywords
Expect:      not bozo and feed['tags'][0]['term'] == 'Technology' and 
'itunes_keywords' not in feed
-->
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/DTDs/Podcast-1.0.dtd">
    <channel>
        <itunes:keywords>Technology</itunes:keywords>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

For the example feed above the entries are:

```
<itunes:keywords>Hurley, Liss, feelings</itunes:keywords>
```

and

```
<itunes:category text="Society &amp; Culture"/>
<itunes:category text="Technology"/>
```

resulting in the `feed[tags]` being populated as so:

```
[{'label': None, 'scheme': 'http://www.itunes.com/', 'term': 'Hurley'},
 {'label': None, 'scheme': 'http://www.itunes.com/', 'term': 'Liss'},
 {'label': None, 'scheme': 'http://www.itunes.com/', 'term': 'feelings'},
 {'label': None,'scheme': 'http://www.itunes.com/','term': 'Society & Culture'},
 {'label': None, 'scheme': 'http://www.itunes.com/', 'term': 'Technology'}]
```

Is there any way to uniquely identify the values that came from the `itunes:category` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with just [feedparser](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser) so I made use of [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) as well:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw_data, "lxml")        

def is_itunes_category(tag):
        return tag.name == 'itunes:category'

categories = [tag.attrs['text'] for tag in soup.find_all(is_itunes_category)]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Feedparser v.6.0.2](https://feedparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest) implements specific `itunes:x` properties

- `itunes:category` is available as `category` in feedparser

```
import feedparser
feedp = feedparser.parse(url)
category = feedp.feed.category
```

- `itunes:keywords` are indeed renamed  `tags` in feedparser and populated into `term`

but channel keywords are mixed with item keywords
to identify item keywords individually use  `scheme` as filter

```
import feedparser
feedp = feedparser.parse(url)
#get all the keywords both item and channel
keywords = [k["term"] for k in feedp["feed"]["tags"]] 
# get the keywords from all the items 
keyword = [t["term"] for t in feedp["feed"]["tags"] if  t["scheme"] == 'http://www.itunes.com/']
```

This may erase the other tags if available but if itunes:keywords and tags they co-exists they are duplicates.

- `itunes:duration` is available as `itunes_duration`

```
import feedparser
feedp = feedparser.parse(url)
duration = feedp["itunes_duration"]
```

A bit out of subject but to complete the answer:

if multiple categories are available they are exposed in categories as tuples
as mentioned in the [documentation](https://feedparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uncommon-rss.html?highlight=itunes#accessing-multiple-categories)

```
>>>import feedparser
>>>feedp = feedparser.parse(url)
>>>categories = feedp.feed.categories 
>>>print(categories)
>>>[(u'Syndic8', u'1024'),
(u'dmoz', 'Top/Society/People/Personal_Homepages/P/')]
```

But itunes as no multiple categories...

There is not anymore needs to parse again with `beautifulSoup4`.